# Program Crashes during object recognition using OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I am using SURF to recognize objects in a video frame. The object recognition function is as follows

```
void objrecognition(Mat* inframe, Mat* inimage, vector<KeyPoint> kp_image, std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners, int num)
{

std::vector<Point2f> obj;
std::vector<Point2f> scene;

Mat des_image, img_matches;
std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
Mat H;


extractor.compute(*inimage, kp_image, des_image);
//matcher.knnMatch(apsobjparam->des_object, des_image, matches, 2);

matcher.knnMatch(sobjectparam[num].des_object, des_image, matches, 2);



for (int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows - 1, (int)matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
{
    if ((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int)matches[i].size() <= 2 && (int)matches[i].size()>0))
    {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
    }
}


if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        //Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj.push_back(sobjectparam[num].kp_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(kp_image[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    //Draw only "good" matches
    //drawMatches(object, kp_object, *inimage, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

    perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

    line(*inframe, scene_corners[0], scene_corners[1], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    line(*inframe, scene_corners[1], scene_corners[2], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    line(*inframe, scene_corners[2], scene_corners[3], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    line(*inframe, scene_corners[3], scene_corners[0], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

}

putText(*inframe,
    sobjectparam[num].label,
    scene_corners[0], // Coordinates
    cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, // Font
    1.0, // Scale. 2.0 = 2x bigger
    cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), // Color
    1, // Thickness
    CV_AA, false); // Anti-alias

imshow("Good Matches", *inframe);



}
```

Where

```
  inframe - is input colour frame from webcam for display

  inimage - is gray scale frame for processing

  kp_image - is the frame keypoints

  des_object - Descriptor of object (Obtained from XML file)

  des_image - Descriptor of current video frame

  sobjectparam - Structure for object keypoints and descriptors
```

I have 3 objects to detect.

The detection is working fine and I am able to draw bounding boxes around objects.

The function call in main is as follows for every frame of the video in infinite while loop :

```
Mat image;

  std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
  cvtColor(frameMat, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

  detector.detect(image, kp_image);


  objrecognition(&frameMat, &image, kp_image, obj_corners, 0);//Deo
  objrecognition(&frameMat, &image, kp_image, obj_corners_two, 1);//Book
  objrecognition(&frameMat, &image, kp_image, obj_corners_three, 2);//Bottle
```

Where,

frameMat - Current video frame

image    - Grayscale frame for processing

- PROBLEM:

The program CRASHES randomly after some time, say 2 minutes on an avg.

I do not understand why it is crashing. Could anyone please explain why this is happening.

- QUESTIONS and MY UNDERSTANDING:

1). Is it because of memory being mismanaged(I thought OpenCvC++) takes care of memory management.

2). Is it because of the multiple function calls for 3 objects(Some arrays are getting mixed up)??

3). Is there anything else I am missing??

4). Should I implement threading??

5). Is it because of the reason explained in my experiments below.

- MY EXPERIMENTS:

1). I saw some issues in the following line

```
matcher.knnMatch(sobjectparam[num].des_object, des_image, matches, 2)
```

where it just crashes sometimes(very rarely) at this line when I use just one object to detect without function call(one single stretch of code without calling the function).  I am suspecting something happens here when the matches are not good.

- **EDITS**:

2). If I get a plain screen(like white paper,palm etc) close to the lens , the program crashes and shows an error like this

Unsupported format or combination of formats  in cv::flann::build index_,file

So there is an issue in the flann based matcher.

- **RESOLVED**

Found the issue :

When I got plain image in front of camera, the image descriptors are ZERO and I am trying to access this UNINITIALIZED BUFFER,hence it was crashing. I put a  check and the issue got resolved.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or any information from the crashes?

Comment: I get the following message: Unhandled exception at 0x769DC54F in Software_ISP_test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0039EF7C.

Comment: Yeah that's not very helpful, eh? Have you run it through a debugger to try to see exactly where it crashes? It will be hard to diagnose without more info

Comment: The problem is, it crashes in some other cpp files which is no where related to object recognition code.

Comment: @Kyle G Please see the edits above

Comment: Was using an Uninitialized buffer hence it was crashing.